# A question on summation notation and pi notation for multiplication.

Tags: summation, notation

As I am in high school, I know the basics to summation and pi notation. However when people put things other than numbers on the top and bottom of the summation, I do not understand what they mean. Can anyone elaborate on some symbols or things I should know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that
the index of summation
has to satisfy
some conditions.

For example,
$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$
can also be written
$\sum_{1 \le i\le n} a_i
$.

Another common idiom
in summation is
$f(n)
=\sum_{d \mid n} g(d)
$.
This means that
$f(n)$
is the sum of
$g(d)$
for all $d$
that exactly divide $n$.
This requires you to know
that the expression
"$d\mid n$"
means that
$d$ exactly divides $n$,
so the sum is taken over
all positive integers $d$ 
which exactly divide $n$.

More generally,
the expression
$f(n)
=\sum_{p(n, d)} g(d)
$
means the sum is taken
over all $d$
such that
$p(n, d)$ is true.

If you don not understand
a particular notation
(and, there are many),
ask.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{i=1}^3f(i)=f(1)+f(2)+f(3)$$

So if we instead put $$\sum_{i=1}^af(i)=f(1)+f(2)+\cdots+f(a)$$
(this only makes sense if $a$ is a positive integer)

Comment: I understand that but sometimes people put some symbols like less than, not equal to,....what does that all mean.